# Assume Role for IAM user to do s3 upload from Jenkins CI

Tags: amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I am trying to use s3upload from Jenkins CI, I have added IAM user S3_User credentials in Jenkins console and using withAWS(region: s3Region ,credentials: s3User). But my IAM user S3_User doesnt have S3 RW policy, IAM user has to assume role S3_UserRoleWithRWpolicy .How do I do that?

Provided S3_User access and secret key in Jenkins IAM credentials and added S3_UserRoleWithRWpolicy in IAM Role to use under IAM Role Support. But still not able to do S3 upload from Jenkins. How could I configure in Jenkins file to use role?

Comment: Can you post your code and error output

Comment: Let me explain in details:   What I am trying to do is S3 upload through Jenkins CI. Credentials I am using to connect to S3 is IAM user secret and access key.                                                                                                                        When I used credentials of IAM user with S3 RW policy attached to it, it works fine but I want to give no permissions to IAM user and attached S3 RW policy role to the user. Not much for the code, in Jenkins CI using, WithAWS(s3User, credentials) { s3Upload...}, Error output says S3 ServiceException, Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution:

I was using this in Jenkins CI file:

```
withAWS(region: 's3Region', credentials: 'iamUser')
{
    s3Upload( file:'jar', bucket:s3Bucket, path: s3Path)
}
```

It worked fine when iamUser has direct access to S3 but failed when iamUser has to assume role to access S3 (after adding IAM Role to Assume in credentials)

But the below worked:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: 'iamUser']]) {
    withAWS(region: 's3Region')
    {
        s3Upload( file:'jar', bucket:s3Bucket, path: s3Path)
    }
}
```